# For what $a,b$ is this integral finite: $\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x)^a}{x^b} dx$

Tags: calculus

The case where $b<1$ is trivial (converge). And for $b \ge 1$, if $a\le 0$, the integral must diverge. I'm not sure what to do with $b \ge 1, a>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is too quick. Write the integral as
$$
\int_0^{1/2}\frac{(1-x)^a}{x^b}\,dx+
\int_{1/2}^1\frac{(1-x)^a}{x^b}\,dx=
\underbrace{\int_0^{1/2}\frac{(1-x)^a}{x^b}\,dx}_I+
\underbrace{\int_0^{1/2}\frac{(1-x)^{-b}}{x^{-a}}\,dx}_J
$$
Note that in both $I$ and $J$ you can disregard the numerators as far as convergence is considered.

The integral
$$
\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{x^b}\,dx
$$
converges for $b<1$ and diverges for $b\ge1$.

Thus you have convergence for $b<1$ and $-a<1$, that is, $a>-1$; divergence for $b\ge1$ or $a\le-1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $b \geq 1$ and $a > 0$, note that
$$
\int_0^{1/2} \frac{(1-x)^a}{x^b}\ dx \geq \int_0^{1/2} \frac{2^{-a}}{x^b}\ dx
$$
hence the integral diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Near $0$ the integrand is equivalent to
$$x^b$$ since
$$(1-x)^a\text{ goes to  } 1.$$

it converges if $-b<1$.

Near $1$, the integrand is equivalent to $$(1-x)^a$$
since $x^b$ goes to $1$.

it converges if $-a<1$.

The inyegral is convergent if $a>-1$ and $b>-1$.

Comment: Equivalent to $x^{-b}$.